# How to make the React component reload upon receiving update on web socket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I have a React JS page which has a table. My requirement is as follows:

- Load the table(Using React Table), call the Data API and populate the table
- Start a web socket connection on the client side and listen for any updates
- The websocket server on the other end sends an update(event) when there is an entry added into the database and hence I need to call the Data API to get the updated info
- Upon receiving any update(basically an event) via the web socket, I need to reload the table component again so that an API call is made to the Data API which will inturn populate the table with new data.

My implementation right now is as follows:

- Load the table, call the API, populate the table
- Open websocket and listen for any updates.
- Upon receiving any updates as events, I call the API again and reload the table.

Im using only React and havent used Redux or MobX for state management.The above method works but I want to know is this the only method or if there is a better method to implement the above?

Comment: Your approach is a viable one. Setting the state on initial API call and rendering the component where the state is passed down as props. You make another request if you receive an update event hence updating the state which will, in turn, re-render the component with new data.
Redux can help you as well. It will allow you to isolate your component from all network related stuff but if your app is a simple one, no need to use it. Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably good to ask yourself how much data is going to be changing, and how many users are going to be using your platform. As those numbers grow your implementation might change, as you don't want to overload your API with requests.

In a project in the past I've used websockets with React/Redux and followed the same path as you have, it performs well and is probably the best you are going to get.

The alternative to your approach that is also sensible is to send the data added to the table alongside the websocket update function, so you don't have to make another call to the Database. I would say that's a better solution for a messaging platform rather than what you are doing. But this could also be a good approach if many users are getting those updates frequently, as it will manage the load on the API a bit better.

I would probably stick to your implementation as it is a viable one but make sure you leave the code in a state where it can be easily changed if needed.